# Create react elements based on array?

Tags: reactjs

So I have a react component here and I have an array from a js file within the app called rwdriver.js. How do i spawn the navlinks for every index in the array?
note the seed data has been changed just so I am not posting actual employee names
Also for the sake of argument we can just say we have a "var employeeArray = [firstname lastname, firstname lastname, firstname lastname]" array in the app.js file where this will be rendered.

```
    function Timetable(){
      return(
        <Table striped bordered hover id='myTable'>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Employee</th>
              <th>Today's Attendance</th>
              <th>Summary</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td id="emplyee table">
                <myTag></myTag>
                <Nav.Item>
                  <Nav.Link eventKey="link-1">600 1800- emp1firstname emp1lastname</Nav.Link>
                </Nav.Item>
                <Nav.Item>
                  <Nav.Link eventKey="link-1">600 1400- emp2firstname emp2lastname</Nav.Link>
                </Nav.Item>
                <Nav.Item>
                  <Nav.Link eventKey="link-1">600 1800- emp3firstname emp3lastname</Nav.Link>
                </Nav.Item>
                
              </td>
              <td>Attendance data</td>
              <td>Summary Data</td>
            </tr>   
            <tr id='botrow'>
              <br></br>
                <p>Memo</p><input id="ip" placeholder="Memo"></input><br></br><br></br>
                <input id="ip" placeholder="Password"></input>
                <br />
                <br></br>
                <Button  variant="primary" size="lg" id="button">Submit</Button>
                <br></br><br></br>
            </tr>     
          </tbody>
        </Table>
        
      );
    }
        export default Timetable;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const people = [{name: 'Mark'}, {name: 'John'}, ...];

...

<div>
   {people.map(person => <p>{person.name}</p>)}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton that helped quite a bit!